# Can we split a file column by :: delimiter in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to read a file which have delimiter as double colon (::). I am using `CSVExcelStorage`, but it is giving error as:

> could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage' with arguments '[::]'

So is there any way to read a file using custom delimiter?

Comment: Did you include the brackets? If so, that isn't correct

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PigStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/PigStorage.html) with your custom delimiter.

Comment: Hi Amit,
i try to use pigstorage with argument but it gives error as shown below:

grunt> a = LOAD '/user/hdfs/test123' using PigStorage('::');
2016-07-14 00:16:34,179 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 2, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'PigStorage' with arguments '[::]'
Details at logfile: /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/pig_1468410234606.log
grunt>

Comment: I tried a sample file with "::" as delimiter and see that PigStorage throws the error "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delimeter must be a single character ::". In this case you will have to write your own loader that would parse the record using multi character delimiters.

Comment: AFAIK `PigStorage` doesn't handle well if the separator is inside quoted text. `CSVExcelStorage` is better for reading csv file with strings.

Comment: I also try the CSVexcel but result was same as given in comment of inquisitive_mind in the below answer

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the quotes.

```
REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD 'Test.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('::')
```

Comment: Hi,
i provide the quotes and use the same syntax as you are suggesting even then it was giving error. The given error is shown below:

grunt> REGISTER /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar;
grunt> a = LOAD '/user/hdfs/test123' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage('::');
 ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 2, column 4> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage' with arguments '[::]'

Comment: @PrakulSinghal The file test123 you are loading doesn't have an extension ?

Comment: yes it doesn't have any extension i even try by adding extension but getting same result

Comment: I think the issue is the path.Try giving the absolute path for the file.Something like this 'hdfs://localhost:9001/user/hdfs/test123'

Comment: same issue even after providing complete path